# Time conflict in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, 16.04

So I have this problem, have Windows 7 and Xubuntu 16.04, dual boot screws time in Windows, tried to change `/etc/default/rcS` as stated in other posts, but UTC = yes line does not appear in that file, never mind, I create the line anyway and set it as stated in those posts, but still when I log into Windows time is wrong again...

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: how is time "screwed"? Shows an hour more, an hour less or what? 
Read the comments on this answer, please. (I'm sure that you'll find solution there)
http://askubuntu.com/a/521177/332981

Comment: I'm from Spain, so it should be UTC+1, in Ubuntu it shows the time correctly (for example, 14:00) and then when I go back to Windows it shows 2 hour less (so, for example, 12:00). I'll check it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/720466/158442) for 16.04

Answer (score 1):

As stated in one comment to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/521177/332981):

> What you need to make sure, that all system you are using are using same setting. Either local time or UTC time. Windows by default uses local time. So if you tweak Ubuntu to local, both systems are in sync and problem should be gone.

Comment: Ubuntu is already set to local, because I wrote the line UTC = no (although it did not exist). If Windows is using local time and Ubuntu too, it should be gone, but it isn't. That's the main problem.

Comment: It's better to [make Windows use UTC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#UTC_in_Windows) since UTC on system clock is more sane. The only ["reason"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040902-00/?p=37983/) Windows uses it is for backward compatibility and "for those who set time through BIOS"

Answer (score 0):

UTC=yes is no longer used in /etc/default/rcS.
See `man 5 rcS`. it says:

> The  EDITMOTD,  RAMRUN  and  UTC variables are no longer used.  The UTC
>          setting is replaced by the UTC or LOCAL setting  in  /etc/adjtime,  and
>          should have been migrated automatically.  See hwclock(5) and hwclock(8)
>          for further details on configuring the system clock.

Comment: So i have to edit etc/adjtime?

Comment: I do not really know. As  Bharadwaj Raju says it is probably  more logical to have windows use UTC.